# How is it possible to define a List, or similar data type. of the same class into a class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I cannot understand how something like that is possible, right now I've an structure like the following in a code I've been passed:

```
public class DayhoursItem {

    @SerializedName("code")
    private String code;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("dayhours")
    private List<DayhoursItem> dayhours;
```

As far as I know in order to use dayhours, you would need to define a DayhoursItem that would need to define a list with a DayHoursItem object that would need to define a list with a DayHoursItem object... and so on.

The code is working but I cannot understand why, so I'd like to know how exactly that can be (how is the way it's behaving).

Comment: Because that is simply not a problem as long as you do not always create an *instance* of `DayhoursItem` and put it in the list. *Then* you have a StackOverflow. Just declaring a nested (recursive) list is no problem.

Comment: You can create an empty list without creating an element to put into the list. What you cannot do is populate the list in the constructor. Note that such a construct is quite common in Tree data structures, where each node has a list of child nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: because any **reference** in java only "identifies" the corresponding object.

This means: when you define a class, and instantiate it, all your fields only *point* to these other objects. Each object has its **own** storage on the heap.

So that `dayhours` field simply points to a List object, that has its storage elsewhere in the heap. And it doesn't matter whether that list is empty, or contains other `DayHourItem` object: there is always only one "pointer" to that list object, from the owning `DayHourItem`.

There is no recursion here. In other languages, similar constructs might very well be illegal.

Of course, when say the **constructor** of the `DayHourItem` class tries to create *another* `DayHourItem` object (to be added to that list), then you have a recursion, and you run out of memory quickly.

So the point is: such "self references" can create problem, but that isn't necessarily always the case.